# Is there any agreement between Putin and NATO?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nato

[This website](https://rediscover911.com/puppet-putin/) has states that:

> On the 23rd of May, 2007, Putin signed an agreement (no 4100940-4) concerning the future intervention of NATO in Russia, in the event of civil disturbances, and natural and technological disasters.

Is there any way to make sure this claim is valid?

Comment: Voting to close due to question lacking details or clarity:  Your suspicions of the website's contents do not justify keeping a link to a source whose claims you want to verify.  There is nothing to stop us from searching and stumbling upon the same source and then confirming that it is true (especially if we believe the same site is credible)?  Additionally, the title question and the question in the body ask two very different things, further confusing a proper response.

Comment: @hszmv the content isn't suspicious to me, but I just thought it'll be suspicious to you, cause I didn't want you deny it only because such a website has stared that. The question is edited, thank you.

Comment: The title Q is trivial to answer as yes, but with different agreements that don't quite match the contents of quote. (Putin himself has an agreement with NATO from 2002 or 2003.) https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_50091.htm

Comment: Generally speaking such Qs about conspiracy theories are more suitable on https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions, but the title (of the post) is expected to more closely match the quote.

Comment: @Fizz this is not a conspiracy theory, since there are agreements between Putin and NATO, the question is related to politics not conspiracies. That's why I didn't want to link

Comment: Some doc ref that only turns up Alex Jones sites does smack of that, sorry.

Comment: @fizz the website isn't for Alex Jones, and the claim is not a conspiracy theory, as yourself and and the deleted answer rightfully mentioned, there are agreements between Putin and NATO, nothing to do with any conspiracy theory, even a broken clock shows the right time twice a day.

Comment: And linking to a site that has as its google summary "Israel Did 911 | We must confront and expose pure evil." is in that bin too.

Comment: Signed a deal saying what?

Comment: @JoeW "concerning the future intervention of NATO in Russia, in the event of civil disturbances, and natural and technological disasters."

Comment: That information should be in your question.

Comment: I just copied this from my question. @JoeW

Comment: @Bootstrap I have reread your question and I am still not sure exactly what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: @JoeW well the point is that Russia attacked Ukraine cause it claimed "it can't tolerate NATO behind its borders", while there's agreements between Russia and NATO which represent some things don't add up about the Russo-Ukraine war, I have found this claim (that Russia and NATO have signed agreements) but I did not find any reference for that, the question is whether such an agreement is really signed or this is just a claim, and I got my answer. Clear enough now?

Comment: @Bootstrap They also claimed to attack Ukraine for a lot of other reasons and not any of them actually look valid. They also signed a deal with them in 1994 which in return for giving up nukes they would honor their independence forever. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction#:~:text=On%20December%205,%201994%20the,a%20preamble%20and%20six%20paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Q: Is there any way to make sure this claim is valid?*

There appears to some conflicts in the quote suggesting the quote is not valid.

On 23 May 2007, Russia ratified the [Partnership for Peace
Status of Forces Agreement](https://www.nato.int/docu/update/2007/05-may/e0523b.html). There is no mention from President Putin's office about signing the agreement -- he was on an [official visit to Austria](http://en.kremlin.ru/events/president/news/by-date/23.05.2007) on that date.

> The PfP SOFA will greatly facilitate further military-to-military cooperation and other practical cooperation between Russia and NATO member states and other Partner countries. In particular, it will make it easier to deploy forces to participate in joint operations and exercises.

While the claim about intervention may have come from the earlier [Founding Act -- on Mutual Relations, Cooperation and Security between NATO and the Russian Federation signed in Paris, France](https://www.nato.int/cps/su/natohq/official_texts_25468.htm) 27 May 1997, it seems unlikely that "future intervention of NATO in Russia" was a goal of the agreement.

> **II. Mechanism for Consultation and Cooperation, the NATO-Russia Permanent Joint Council**

> Any actions undertaken by NATO or Russia, together or separately, must be consistent with the United Nations Charter and the OSCE's governing principles.

> **III. Areas for Consultation and Cooperation**

> - conducting joint initiatives and exercises in civil emergency preparedness and disaster relief;

Comment: Russia also "unratified" the PfP a bit later, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Also the PfP SOFA was *signed* in April 2005 (by Lavrov, not Putin) https://www.nato.int/docu/update/2005/04-april/e0421a.htm 2007 is when the Duma ratified that. I suppose when the Duma ratified it, Putin might have countersigned it too.

Comment: @fizz thanks for the reply, Is there any way to make sure Russia has "unratified" or not? I did a little digging but found nothing.

Comment: @Bootstrap: I think I misremembered and they didn't make it formal... although as Putin likes to joke about the Paris [climate] agreement: "have you read what it says?"

Answer (score 4):

To answer the title Q, for all practical purposes those agreements [are](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_50091.htm) talk clubs at best right now:

> In April 2014, following Russia’s illegal and illegitimate annexation of Crimea, the Alliance suspended all practical cooperation between NATO and Russia. However, the Alliance agreed to keep channels of communication open in the NRC and the Euro-Atlantic Partnership Council at the Ambassadorial level and above, to allow the exchange of views, first and foremost on the crisis in Ukraine.

NRC = [NATO-Russia Council](https://www.nato.int/nrc-website/en/about/index.html).

[Also](https://www.politico.com/news/2021/10/18/russia-suspends-mission-nato-shuts-office-516189) even the formal representation of Russia at NATO was withdrawn by the former in October last year, after NATO expulsed some diplomats on spying charges.

> Russia’s Foreign Ministry said in a separate statement that NATO’s actions “confirm that they are not interested in an equal dialogue and joint work to deescalate military-political tensions.”